# error #1238 when updating datetime format variable

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mamp, mamp-pro

I'm attempting to change the **MySQL** global variable `datetime_format` to use zulu time (`%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%sZ`) inside my application.

I've never had any issues running this command on localhost before and I cannot find a way to do it without receiving this error:

> #1238 - Variable 'datetime_format' is a read only variable

On MAMP Pro I have access to the `my.cnf` file, but this doesn't let me set any default variables for startup.

Is there a way I can bypass this and/or set default variables when starting up **MySQL** or will I have to find an alternative local server?

Comment: This variable was removed since 8.0.3. So its usage not recommended.

Comment: @Akina Currently on version 5.7.34, so not really a concern right now. :-)

Comment: For your version (and even for version 5.6.x) the Reference Manual tells that *This variable is unused. It is deprecated and is removed in MySQL 8.0.* https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_datetime_format I do not see the reason to adjust the variable if it is not used... changed value will alter nothing.

Comment: @Akina Because it is currently, incorrectly, formatting my database entries from zulu time to `%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s` format. Unless this is a separate issue?

Comment: *#1238 - Variable 'datetime_format' is a read only variable* Server tells this because this is global variable whereas you try to alter session one.

Comment: *it is currently, incorrectly, formatting my database entries from zulu time to %Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s format.* Do you see incorrect datetime value formatting while using CLI? I doubt... test please. You must receive only standard YYYY-MM-DD HH:ii:ss datetime value. If you need another output format then use DATE_FORMAT() function with needed pattern.

Comment: @Akina I cannot use the CLI as I'm using the MAMP interface. I'm inserting the data via PHP in zulu time format. On insert, I will receive the error `Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect datetime value: '2022-09-26T10:15:17Z'`

Comment: This is Php issue which provides incorrect datetime format to MySQL. Use STR_TO_DATE() in INSERT/UPDATE query. Or adjust Php (not MySQL) setting.

Answer (score 0):

To set datetime format, you need to add it inside your my.cnf file.

In MAMP you need to follow below steps:

1. Stop servers
2. Create a my.cnf file in /Applications/MAMP/conf/
3. Add your content in to my.cnf
4. Save my.cnf
5. Start servers

Comment: No dice, my friend.